# как запустить в одной функции два последовательных request запроса?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

нужно последовательно запустить два request запроса(модуль в javascript), условия не асинхронно.

```
request(url, function(err, res, body){

    some code

  }).then(() {
    request(url_next_link, function(err, res, bodys){
some another code
})
```

это то как я пробовал) ну как бы не работает такой варик)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка в коде

```
.then(() { // <== это что такое???
    request(url_next_link, function(err, res, bodys){
        some another code
    })
})
```

Если используете `request`, то он умеет возвращать `Promise` ( [ссылка](https://github.com/request/request-promise) ) и тогда вашу задачу можно решить через `async/await`

```
async function getServerData() {
    const result = await request(url, data);
    const result1 = await request(url2, result);
    return result1;
}

const result2 = getServerData();
```

Можно написать свою обертку простую

```
const asyncRequest = (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(...args, function(err, res, bodys) {
        if(err) reject(err);
        resolve(res, bodys);
    }
});
```

Используем

```
const {res, bodys} = await asyncRequest(url, data);
const {res, bodys} = await asyncRequest(url2, data2);
```

Comment: а можно засунуть реквест в одну отдельную функцию(отправляя разные url) и получать promise, через return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { request....
если да то что нужно возвращать в resolve и что в await писать

Comment: request и request-promise это разные библиотеки

Comment: @Jumper я приложил же ссылку, там есть инструкция по установке, где нужен `request`